# YouTube - how to determine which ads are scheduled to play

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to determine which ads (and any information about those ads) are schedule to play, from any particular youtube request or URI?

TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, afraid not.  Since the ads are targeted (on request) by user as well as content, you wouldn't be able to get anything but targeting data for any channel not under sponsorship if Google gave access to the systems, anyway.